# Insert task to GAE Push Queue from GCE instance in PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, google-api-php-client

I'm looking for an example (or info if it's even possible) to insert tasks into Google AppEngine Push Task Queue from a Google Compute Engine instance in PHP.

Basicaly how turn this:

```
use google\appengine\api\taskqueue\PushTask;

$task = new PushTask('/worker', ['name' => 'john doe', 'action' => 'send_reminder']);
$task_name = $task->add();
```

into something that can run on GCE instance. Could be with https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess [that](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/glossary#push_queue) answers my question.

> You can use push queues only within the App Engine environment; if you need to access App Engine tasks from outside of App Engine, use pull queues instead.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to create an endpoint on your GAE App which can then be called by your GCE instance with parameters which can be handled by the endpoint to enqueue tasks within GAE.

For example, to handle tasks which require more memory (128MB)  or data (100KB) than TaskQueue allows, I have a GCE instance running a Flask app which my GAE app calls as part of a scheduled task.  The GCE instance performs the large task then sends the results back to GAE when done by making an HTTP request to an endpoint on my GAE app which then uses those results to enqueue other tasks.  If my GCE large task wasn't too large, I could return results to in the HTTP response instead of making a new HTTP request.

Comment: Yes, I've ended up doing exact same thing :) However this doesn't feel right from architecture perspective